# How to programmatically Find / Debug (Find Location) of the missing `End If`

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a long code on worksheet event which contains a lot of IF conditions and nested IF. 
Sometimes, I forget to add the end if ,so when I debug the code ,got this `Compile error:Block If without End If`.
The error meaning is very clear , and I depend on my eye to find this missing IF. 
Because the code on worksheet event , I cannot use F8 (Step Into). 
**So**, Is there any programmatic method to Find / Debug (**Find Location**) of the missing `End If`.
In advance, grateful for any helpful comments and answer.

Comment: That error can be due to different reasons, not simply because of the lack of `End If`. e.g. a `With` statement without `End With` inside an `If` block will prompt this error as well. Indent your codes properly and it should be easier to spot the error. Update your question with the code and maybe someone will spot it? You can also copy/paste the code into a regular module to test it.

Comment: Use indenting for the if-clauses - then it is pretty easy to not miss the end-if-statement. Also: it might be useful to split the code to avoid a lot of indenting.

Comment: [Rubberduck VBA](https://rubberduckvba.com/) is a free Add-In that has a Code Indenter.  The Code Indenter will help find mismatched statements.

Comment: Watching [Master VBA Debugging in 20 Minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Um2JwZfwoFI) will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Consider that the VBA compiler would not need and ENDIF if it was able identify where it should end. You can place ENDIF at different locations to achieve different program execution flow. Your best bet is to nicely format all your code, indenting blocks as @RaymondWu suggested, revealing anomalies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go through your code make sure you have no single line `If (condition) Then (do something)` statements. Means after every `Then` is a line break and no statement following in that line. The statements follow in the next line below and are closed with an `End If`.

```
If a Then b = 1  ' single line statement
```

avoid them and use always blocks like

```
If a Then
    b = 1
End If
```

This looks a bit cumbersome but makes it much easier to find issues.

Then go through your code make sure you indent everything correctly. This way you will find out if there are any blocks that are not closed.

Note that the error message might be missleading and does not come from a missing `End If`. Even your compiler tells you that, it just means that the compiler was waiting for an `End If` where something else came, so it just couldn't find it in the expected position:

For example if you just mix up the position of `End If` and `End With` and you have a bad code formatting like below, you will get the missing `End If` compiler message:

```
If Condition = True Then

With ActiveSheet


End If

End With
```

But if you indent your code correctly and format it nicely you will easily see that something is wrong:

```
If Condition = True Then
    With ActiveSheet

    End If  ' should be `End With` inner block needs to close first
End With
```

Now you cleary see that `End If` and `End With` got mixed up and don't match their `If` and `With`. In nested blocks, the inner blocks need always to be closed first.